# Binary Classification Probabilities

Tags: keras, r, time-series, finance

I'm using keras in R to predict financial time series. I guess that ANN converges.
 [image]

But when I do predictions I can see that probabilities don't sum up to 1

[image]

I'm using `relu` as final activation and `loss = "binary_crossentropy"`.
Does that mean the net doesn't converge or do I miss something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if input to a neural netwrk are scaled or normalised, the raw output values can still go outside of that range.

In your case, the output values are being interpreted as to make a binary YES/NO decision, but the raw values cannot necessarily be interpreted as raw probabilities! They are merely the final activations of the network.

To get what you expect, the final activations are usually passed through a `softmax` function, which essentially *squashes* the values you see in your table to sum to 1 on each row - this allows us to treat them as probabilities to make the final classification.

In practice, this means simply adding the softmax activation to your final `Dense` layer in Keras (`activation="softmax"`) and then compile the model using:
 `loss="categorical_crossentropy"`

Comment: I'm using `relu` as final activation and `loss = "binary_crossentropy"`

Comment: It is general advised not to use a non-linear activation in the final output, as this adds a step which the last layer doesn't directly decide - or rather it has to really learn how a ReLU works. It is unnecessary. If you want that layer there, just add another one on top with the `sigmoid` activation.

Answer (score 0):

As you have 2 numbers, your network has two output nodes. For example, Female and Male. In binary classification the output nodes are independent and the prediction for each node is from 0 to 1. So, you should consider a threshold (usually 0.5). Then if the prediction value is upper than this threshold for Male, you consider the image as Male.